# ng-pattern not matching the correct regex

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern, angularjs-ng-pattern

I am using a form to get user details. In my name input I want only alphabetic characters, spaces and apostrophe. So I created the form input like

```
<input placeholder="FULL NAME" type="text" ng-model="customer.name" ng-pattern="/([a-zA-Z'\s])+/" ng-required="true">
```

However in my form if I give input hyphen or underscore characters it is still taking as a valid input. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: see this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952077/why-is-angularjs-ng-pattern-not-working-with-the-following-regexp/25484623#25484623"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey all so the solution for my problem was just to change

```
ng-pattern="/([a-zA-Z'\s])+/"
```

to

```
ng-pattern="/^([a-zA-Z'\s])+$/"
```

So now input element looks like this

```
<input placeholder="FULL NAME" type="text" ng-model="customer.name" ng-pattern="/^([a-zA-Z'\s])+$/" ng-required="true">
```