# Email validation failed when have 4 characters after @ in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This is very Basic issue of angular but I am unable to fix this; I want to validate email address using `ng-pattern` but it failed on some condition
see the [working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/rh8yFra2eqs4TtbyB8w6?p=preview)

failed condition : when i write `some@thing`  it validated OK but that is not correct. Kindly help me to solve this veri basic issue.

```js
(function() {

var app = angular.module('app', []); 
app.controller ('MainCtrl', function ($scope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.title = "Email Validation";
  vm.email = "";
  vm.email_regex = '^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$';
 
});
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <h2>{{vm.title}}</h2>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form name="emailForm" novalidate="">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': emailForm.username.$touched && emailForm.username.$invalid }">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="col-md-12 form-control" name="username" ng-model="vm.email" ng-pattern="vm.email_regex" required />
        </div>
        <div ng-if="emailForm.username.$touched && emailForm.username.$invalid" ng-messages="emailForm.username.$error" class="text-danger">
          <span ng-message="pattern">Invalid Username.</span>
          <span ng-message="required">Please enter Username.</span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <hr />
    <pre>{{ emailform.username.$error | json }}</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't Angular have a built-in email address format validator?

Comment: that also failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `' '`
 from `vm.email_regex`

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/tbLP5syvZEq7qtE4X75o?p=preview

Refer this: [Why is Angularjs ng-pattern not working with the following regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952077/why-is-angularjs-ng-pattern-not-working-with-the-following-regexp/25484623#25484623)

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('app', []); 

app.controller ('MainCtrl', function ($scope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.title = "Email Validation";
  vm.email = "";
  vm.email_regex = /^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;

});
})();
```

Comment: This seems at odds with the [`ng-pattern` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)

Comment: @Phil True. I still  remeber when I was facing the same issue. It was 2 complete days

Comment: Welcome @pro.mean.